# function that works for lapply returns error for parLapply

Tags: r, lapply, doparallel

I have a function that I am using with lapply and it works fine. I have tried to convert the lapply to a parLapply, and now it returns a `error on cluster node 1 processing element 1: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Is this an issue with how I am setting up the parallel environment, or is it something else?

The function I am using:

```
setLimits<-function(col){
    if(choice=="num"){
        if (auto=="0"){
            high=inHigh[count]
            low=inLow[count]
        }
        else{
            high=inHigh[1]
            low=inLow[1]    
        }
    }
    else{
        if (auto=="0"){
            high=attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.upper+attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.upper*(inHigh[count]/100)
            low=attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.lower+attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.lower*(inLow[count]/100)
        }
        else{
            high=attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.upper+attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.upper*(inHigh[1]/100)
            low=attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.lower+attributes(dt[,col])$SpotfireColumnMetaData$limits.prod.lower*(inLow[1]/100)
        }
    }
    list(low,high)
}
```

The setup:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
cluster<-makeCluster(numCores)
inHigh<-[100,5000,340,6532,45325,645345,2342,2466]
inLow<-[-432,-34325,-5342-,643,234,234,234,1]
x=ncol(dt)
```

calling the parlApply:

```
inVal=parLapply(cl=cluster,X=1:ncol(dt),fun=setLimits)
```

calling the lapply:

```
inVal=lapply(1:ncol(dt),setLimits)
```

Sorry I won't be able to provide dt and `dput` doesn't appear to work for the program I am using. dt is stored as a data.frame. I did simplify the function a little, but I tried to keep the main things that happen in it.

Comment: Did you use `clusterExport` to copy `dt` to the cluster nodes? I think the clusters are seeing `dt` as the function `stats::dt`. You should also export `choice`, `count` and any other objects in your function that are required but not given as function arguments.

Comment: @BenBarnes those are saved as global variables, do i still need to export them? Also dt is pretty big, so would exporting it make it a lot slower?

Comment: If you're using WIndows, then yes, you'll have to export global variables. If you're using Linux/Mac, you can fork. See http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/ for a good overview

Comment: Yeah you need to. From what I see above, maybe you can create a list of all your column attributes first. Then maybe you don't even need to loop through

Comment: @BenBarnes for some reason I am getting that the dt object is not found. I think it has something to do with the the program that I am using r with. Is there anyway to have the two inputs itterate at the same time, or use the X input value in another arguement? So like in my case parLapply(cl=cluster,X=1:ncol(dt),fun=setLimits, arg2= dt[,X])

Comment: This is not a reproducible example.